# Most efficient way to find the closest integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table in a MySQL database from which I want to select the row with the closest timestamp to another given timestamp.

`time` is the timestamp column (an integer UNIX timestamp). I chose `1250710000` arbitrarily.

This is the query that I've come up with, and I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it:

```
SELECT *, ABS(time - 1250710000) AS time_dist FROM table
 ORDER BY time_dist ASC LIMIT 1
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `time` is indexed, you can get the *next* record nearly for free:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > 1250710000 ORDER BY time LIMIT 1
```

And if I'm not wrong, the same should apply to the previous record, MySQL will just read the index in reverse order. Use an UNION of the two, order them by date diff and voila! The result will look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    (SELECT *, ABS(time - 1250710000) AS time_diff FROM table WHERE time > 1250710000 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT *, ABS(time - 1250710000) AS time_diff FROM table WHERE time < 1250710000 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)
) AS tmp
ORDER BY time_diff
LIMIT 1
```

Ideally, instead of `>` and `<` you should use `>=` and `<=` and exclude the reference record using its primary id, to account for records sharing the same timestamp.

Comment: Great idea, but the reference timestamp (`1250710000` in this case) isn't in the same table.

Having said that, I assume that this query is about the same in terms of efficiency?

Comment: **@cyouung:** This query is not the same in terms of efficiency. Your query does an `ABS(time - 125071000)` on *every single row*. As long as you have an index on `time`, this query will never read more than two rows.

Answer (score 1):

As Evan said, the way you have it is fine.  I would recommend an index on that timestamp field, so that MySQL can scan the smaller index rather than the whole table.  Also, I would try some 'boxing' to see if the index can speed things up:

```
SELECT *, ABS(time - 1250710000) AS time_dist FROM table 
WHERE time between(1250610000,1250810000)
ORDER BY time_dist ASC LIMIT 1
```

The above limits to query to approximately +/- 1 day.  You will have to do some benchmarks to see if the additional index scan (the where clause) is faster than computing ABS() on all entries in the table.

Comment: I dislike having arbitrary limits like that.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be more efficient to select the minimum time that is larger and the maximum
time that is smaller then just abs those two. That should avoid having to operate on the 
entire table.

SELECT MAX(time) AS prev WHERE time < 1250710000;

SELECT MIN(time) AS next WHERE time > 1250710000;

SELECT MIN(ABS(prev), ABS(next));

My SQL isn't strong enough to combine those into one, and the overhead of three
queries might kill any savings, but it might be possible.